# Describe the separable closure of $\mathbb F_3(u,v)$ in $\mathbb F_3(y,z)$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I'm struggling with the separable closure problem and
I don't understand some points.

> Let $y,z$ be indeterminates and let $u=y^{12}$ and $v={y^2}{z^{18}}$. Describe the separable closure of $\mathbb F_3(u,v)$ in $\mathbb F_3(y,z)$.

The separable closure contains $y^3$.
Then it must contain $z^{54}$ and hence must contain $z^{27}$.
Since it must also contain $y^2{z^{18}}$, the separable closure is $\mathbb F_3(y^3, y^2{z^{18}}, z^{27})$. Thus $\mathbb F_3(y,z)$ is totally inseparable over this field.

I don't understand why

1. the separable closure contains $y^3$ and $z^{27}$.
   I guess it is because characteristic is 3. Is it right?
2. the separable closure contains $y^2{z^{18}}$.
   Why "must" the separable closure contain it?